# How to assign an ID to each replaced string in preg_replace and get a list of matched words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, array-map

I already have a code that works, but i need to add two additional features. This code basically replaces all bad words form a sentence, and replaces it with dots (leaving the first word of the letter visible for the reader).

The new features I need to add:

1. Assign an html span with a unique ID (autoincremental) to each replaced string in preg_replace
2. Add all matched words (including repeated instances) in a php variable, in the same  order.

This is my current code:

```
function sanitize_badwords($string) {
    $list = array(
        "dumb",
        "stupid",
        "brainless"
    );

    # use array_map to generate a regex of array for each word
    $relist = array_map(function($s) {
        return '/(?:\b(' . $s[0] . ')(?=' . substr($s, 1) . '\b)|(?!\A)\G)\pL/';
    }, $list);

    # call preg_replace using list of regex
    return preg_replace($relist, '<span id="bad_'.$counter.'">$1.</span>', $string);
}

echo sanitize_badwords('You are kind of dumb and brainless. Very dumb!');
```

The current code prints:

> You are kind of d... and b......... Very d....!

After implementing the first feature, the result should be:

```
You are kind of <span id="bad_1">d...</span> and <span id="bad_2">b........</span>. Very <span id="bad_3">d...</span>!
```

The second feature should allow me to have a single php array that has all the matched words (including repeated instances):

```
$matches = array('dumb', 'brainless', 'dumb');
```

*The reason I need this, is that I cannot print bad words in the crawlable html for ToS reasons, but I still need to display the bad word on mouseover via javascript later (I can easily take the contents of $matches and convert that to a javascript array and assign them to the hover state of all the bad_ids spans).*

Comment: look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback()` and pass the `$counter` reference to increment it :

```
$list = array("dumb", "stupid", "brainless");
$string = 'You are kind of dumb and brainless. Very dumb!';


// See comments below - Many thanks @revo
usort($list, function($a,$b) { return strlen($b) < strlen($b); }); 

$counter = 0 ; // Initialize the counter
$list_q = array_map('preg_quote', $list) ; // secure strings for RegExp


// Transform the string
$string = preg_replace_callback('~(' . implode('|',$list_q) . ')~', 
    function($matches) use (&$counter) {
       $counter++;
       return '<span id="bad_' . $counter . '">'
           . substr($matches[0], 0, 1)
           . str_repeat('.', strlen($matches[0]) - 1)
           . '</span>' ;
}, $string);

echo $string;
```

Will outputs :

```
You are kind of <span id="bad_1">d...</span> and <span id="bad_2">b........</span>. Very <span id="bad_3">d...</span>!
```

---

Using a function, that stores the matches in `$references` variable :

```
function sanitize_badwords($string, &$references) {

    static $counter  ;
    static $list  ;
    static $list_q  ;

    if (!isset($counter)) {
        $counter = 0 ;
        $list = array("dumb", "stupid", "brainless");

        // See comments below - Many Thanks @revo
        usort($list, function($a,$b) { return strlen($b)< strlen($b) ; }); 

        $list_q = array_map('preg_quote', $list);
    }

    return preg_replace_callback('~('.implode('|',$list_q).')~',
        function($matches) use (&$counter, &$references){
            $counter++;
            $references[$counter] = $matches[0];
            return '<span id="bad_'.$counter.'">'
               . substr($matches[0],0,1)
               . str_repeat('.', strlen($matches[0])-1)
               . '</span>' ;

    }, $string) ;
}

$matches = [] ;
echo sanitize_badwords('You are kind of dumb and brainless. Very dumb!', $matches) ;


print_r($matches);
```

Will outputs :

```
You are kind of <span id="bad_1">d...</span> and <span id="bad_2">b........</span>. Very <span id="bad_3">d...</span>!

Array
(
    [1] => dumb
    [2] => brainless
    [3] => dumb
)
```

Comment: Great approach! And how can I actually get a list of all the matched words in a single variable (including repeated matches)?

Comment: @andufo i've updated the anwser to use a function. For your comment, I'm not sure to understand. You want an array of matches?

Comment: @andufo In the output array, the indices matches to the span ID. In the last update :)

Comment: I was testing the previous version of your code. This version works perfectly. Thanks! Accepted answer.

Comment: The `$string` re-assignment in the middle of the function is a small mistake and could cause confusion later on. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @jh1711 Oh! You're right! I'll change that. Thank you

Comment: You should take care about words too. If a word for example `dumb-ass` is in list but under `dumb` then results would be replacing `dumb` in input string and leaving `-ass` intact. @andufo

Comment: @revo great point, it is difficult to control all possible combinations, unless each bad word was listed as a regexp.

Comment: @andufo @revo You're right! Thank you. Just using `rsort($list_q);` will made the tricks. I'll update the anwser.

Comment: You have to sort values based on length: longest to shortest. `rsort` isn't what you really need like with `['badman', 'man']` which will be sorted as ``['man', 'badman']`` leading to an unexpected result.

Comment: @revo Right again! Thanks a lot for the review! I'll fix that.

Comment: @revo Fixed (I think). Using `usort()` and `strlen()` (`mb_strlen()`) should be even better. Thank you so much!

Comment: You got my +1 @Syscall

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I ended using data-index="'.$counter.'" instead of id. That way is easier to connect it with the $matches data via Javascript afterwards.